# Why npm is mandatory for angular?

Tags: angular, npm

I am almost new to angular.

I  worked on an Angular 2 project, not from the scratch though. What I observed is there are couple of `.js` file which has 'app and controller' code and the html has the Angular specific attribute like `ng-*`.

Now I am trying to migrate a jsp project to a angular ( 4 or 5) project. And all the tutorials are telling the npm is mandatory. But I am not clear, what is the purpose. If I just create those `js` file with `controller` and `App` and integrate into `html`. Won't that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a comment to keep in mind: AngularJS stands for 1.x, versions >=2 are now consistently called just Angular.

All the Angular `ng` tools are written for NodeJS, and npm is the default package manager for NodeJS. You won't be able to compile your Angular application without npm.

This was not the case with AngularJS (1.x). Back then, you could just write a static application and include a distribution version of `angular.js`.

Comment: That make sense. I just mixed-up both the version of angular. Thanks for the clarification !!